# QML Video element randomly disappears on Label text change

Tags: qt, qml

I'm working on an app which is supposed to display a camera stream from a webcam. It's a single-page app which only shows a `Video` QML element showing the stream (which currently is a simple `.avi` file) and a `Label` element indicating the current connection state from an MQTT connection.

Here's the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtMultimedia 5.12
import MqttClient 1.0

Window {
    width: 360
    height: 640
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Doorbell")

    MqttClient {
        id: client

        // TODO
        property string _host: "localhost"
        property string _port: "1883"
        property string _topic: "my/topic"

        hostname: _host
        port: _port

        Component.onCompleted: {
            connectToHost()
        }

        onConnected: {
            subscribe(_topic)
        }

        onMessageReceived: {
            video.play()
        }

        Component.onDestruction: {
            disconnectFromHost()
        }
    }

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        columns: 2

        Video {
            id: video
            objectName: "vplayer"
            width: parent.width
            height: 300
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            autoPlay: false
            source: "file:///path/to/my/test.avi"

            onErrorChanged: {
                console.log("error: " + video.errorString)
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    video.muted = !video.muted
                }
            }

            focus: true

            Image {
                id: muteIndicator
                source: "mute_white.png"

                width: 64
                height: width

                visible: video.muted

                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }

        Label {
            function stateToString(value) {
                if (value === 0)
                    return "Disconnected"
                else if (value === 1)
                    return "Connecting"
                else if (value === 2)
                    return "Connected"
                else
                    return "Unknown"
            }

            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            text: stateToString(client.state) + "(" + client.state + ")"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: working screenshot]

Here's the clue:
I tried removing the Label and replacing it with a simple rectangle indicator (red or green) to show if the connection is currently active.

However, when replacing the `text` content of the `Label` element, the `Video` element completely disappears.

What I've tried:

- removing the `stateToString(client.state) + "(" + client.state + ")"` part and replacing it with `text: "Connected(2)"`
- replacing `stateToString(...` with an empty string (`text: ""`)
- replacing the content of `stateToString(...)` with `return "Connected(2)"`
- and a lot of different more seemingly completely useless things

Example code:

```
// ...

Label {
    function stateToString(value) {
        if (value === 0)
            return "Disconnected"
        else if (value === 1)
            return "Connecting"
        else if (value === 2)
            return "Connected"
        else
            return "Unknown"
    }

    Layout.columnSpan: 2
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    text: "Connected(2)"
    //          enabled: client.state === MqttClient.Connected
}

// ...
```

Unless I set `text` **to the exact value** `stateToString(client.state) + "(" + client.state + ")"` or at least `stateToString(client.state)`, the `Video` element will **always** disappear in the QML view:

[image: non-working example]

I have no idea of what might be the reason for this.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
Layout.fillWidth: true
```

after:

```
objectName: "vplayer"
```

I'm 99% sure the root of the problem is in the way you have used the layouts. In another word, you have not placed your QML elements in a robust way. since QML has so much flexibility in positioning elements in UI, it matters in QML to put your elements in a well-defined, robust way.